# Ocean 2010.1 with VS2010

Tags: ocean, petrel

Can I use Ocean for petrel 2010.1 with VS.2010 to write petrel plug ins?

I ask because I need to use some specific features on the .NET  4.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wizard that comes with the Ocean SDK for Petrel 2011.1 actually works with Visual Studio 2010 as well as Visual Studio 2008. You can take advantage of .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 features in your plug-in, but depending on which version of Petrel you are targeting you need to make sure the dependent .NET assemblies are available for your plug-in at runtime.

Comment: You can download the latest Ocean SDK from www.ocean.slb.com/developers (log in => "Download Ocean Releases")

Answer (score 1):

You can use VS 2010 if you do not need the Wizard to generate Ocean stub code.

Petrel 2010 uses .Net 2.0. This means you can use features up to 3.5, but not 4.0.

Rumor is that Petrel 2012 might use .Net 4.0 when it ships.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use and wizards also. You just need to change Projects and Items templates location in VS Tools->Options... to appropriate location where your Ocean templates was installed. It should be like C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates. By default it may contain path to ...Documents and Settings.. which is wrong.